# Python missing from /venv/bin/python folder in virtual environment Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, setup.py

I’ve recently migrated across to a new Mac computer and now when I try and run a Python file within a Pycharm virtual environment I get the message

> Cannot Run program `{Virtual_Environment_name}/venv/bin/python` in directory `{Virtual_Environment_name}/venv/bin/python`, error = 2, "No such file or directory"

It looks like Python is not installed in the folder `{Virtual_Environment_name}/venv/bin/python`.

How can I install Python at this location? Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 0):

At the right bottom corner, there's an interpreter selection button. Press it. Now you've got two options:

- Interpreter settings
- Add interpreter...

[image: Selecting an interpreter]

Choose `Interpreter settings`. Your interpreter should be marked red, as it is not found. Press the `gear button` at the right and ask to `Show all...` interpreters. You may choose to edit your interpreter's path here, or remove the interpreter and make it anew.

[image: Buttons to click]